# Read from a *.txt file lines with 10, 20 even 30 hashtags ("#######...)

Tags: python

I know there are examples on how to extract hashtags from strings.  What I am interested is to read a text file line by line , even if it has some lines with hashtags not one but a bunch i.e. "######## line information ######".

Comment: What problem are you finding with your code? From your description, I can't see any obvious reason why this can't be done with python, so it's not very clear where you need help?

Comment: A hashtag is just a normal character (`'#'`). You can handle it just as any other string.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('file.txt')
line = f.readline()
while line:
    line = line.replace('#', '')
    print(line)
    line = f.readline()
f.close()
```

Let me know if you need anything else.